# Wireless connection keeps dropping

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have a wireless network at home, to which I connect using a laptop and a desktop.  Everything has been working well for several months, but recently my desktop (WinXP) developed a problem: it drops the network connection, then reconnects, then a few seconds later drops it again, reconnects, etc.

The signal strength shows up as "Excellent".  The laptop (Win7) still connects to the network without any trouble.  So I would have guessed that the wireless card in the desktop has gone on the fritz... except that my workaround seems to be rebooting the router!  Whenever this starts happening, I just reboot the wireless router, and now the desktop connects and stays connected... until the same problem recurs a couple of days later.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Did you confirm that it is the network connection between the computer and the router that drops? For example, did you try pinging the router and confirming that it fails?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - thanks for reminding me of this problem.  I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the router.  I got a new one and the problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a problem with access point which now has to be reset and probably firmware upgraded and reset again.

Answer (score 0):

Do a wireless survey several times.  You may have a nearby Access Point that is conflicting with your AP.  See if you can find an unused channel and set your AP to that.  Most APs automatically select and then there can be conflicts.  [HeatMap](http://www.ekahau.com/products/heatmapper/overview.html)  works well as does [Netstumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/downloads/).  It is important to do this several times, especially at times when you have an issue.

Resetting your AP may change channel so that does a temporary fix.

You should also be sure the AP has clean power.  Small dips in voltage can cause issues.  A small UPS can address this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. When the network is up (after you rebooted the access point) try to open a command prompt and ping the router indefinitely.

```
ping -t ip_of_access_point
```

If that works and the connection stays alive probably  the Access Point capacitors are exhausted and the AP need to be fixed or replaced.